# Selenium Webdriver in c# usage of Sessionid

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

What is the Use of SessionID in Selenium Webdriver?

Consider a scenario having opened 5 Browsers each having its own sessionid. Can we use these sessionid's to close their respective browsers ? if so, how do we do that in C# ?

Answer (score 2):

Having session ID handy could help you connect with your session on a remote web driver. 
You can fetch the session ID with :

```
var sessionIdProperty = typeof(RemoteWebDriver).GetProperty("sessionId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); //sessionId
if (sessionIdProperty != null)
{
    SessionId sessionId = sessionIdProperty.GetValue(driver, null) as SessionId;
    sId = sessionId.ToString();//((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities.GetCapability("webdriver.remote.sessionid").ToString();
}
```

After that - You may be able to reconnect to the session by using :

```
IWebDriver driverReUse = new ReuseRemoteWebDriver(uri, sId);
```

Given that you have a class that allows reuse of a remote webdriver.

```
public class ReuseRemoteWebDriver : OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver
{
    private String _sessionId;

    public ReuseRemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, String sessionId)
        : base(remoteAddress, new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities())
    {
        this._sessionId = sessionId;
        var sessionIdBase = this.GetType()
            .BaseType
            .GetField("sessionId",
                      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        sessionIdBase.SetValue(this, new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.SessionId(sessionId));
    }

    protected override OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response
        Execute(string driverCommandToExecute, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        if (driverCommandToExecute == OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverCommand.NewSession)
        {
            var resp = new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response();
            resp.Status = OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverResult.Success;
            resp.SessionId = this._sessionId;
            resp.Value = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Object>();
            return resp;
        }
        var respBase = base.Execute(driverCommandToExecute, parameters);
        return respBase;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the session ID is an internal implementation detail with which an end user should not have to concern themselves. A browser session can be terminated, along with the running browser instance, by calling the `.Quit()` method. To wit:

```
// Launch one instance of Firefox
IWebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();

// Launch a second instance of Firefox,
// which can be controlled independently
// of the first.
IWebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();

// Exit the first Firefox instance (the second
// remains running.
driver1.Quit();

// Exit the second instance.
driver2.Quit();
```

However, it must be noted that WebDriver can only manipulate browser instances started via WebDriver. There is no way at present to connect to an existing, running browser instance, nor is there likely to be.

Comment: ok let me put it this way, i have a loop for (i=0;i<5;i++) { Iwebdriver dr=new firefoxDriver(); dr.url="http://something.com" } this opens 5 sessions having its own sessionid's .. and i want to close browser 2 and 4 out of 5 opened browsers, can we do this by getting the sessionid's ?

Comment: It is not possible to close the browsers based on the session ID as what was clearly explained by @JimEvans. In order to close corresponding browsers, you need to get WindowHandles first and then use it for closing the browsers.

Comment: I do not believe WindowHandles will work here as each browser has been opened by different drivers rather than a browser spawning other browsers. In your example you could store each driver in an array or dictionary and call "quit" as required

Comment: @SrikrishnaMajety In your code posted in your comment, you are abandoning the instance of the browser each time through the loop by reusing the variable. As @RobbieWareham suggests, you'd be better off adding each new instance to a collection like a `List<IWebDriver>` or a `Dictionary<string, IWebDriver>`, and manipulating them that way.